# Adding with variables whose storage is decided through a text box

Tags: javascript, variables, math, textbox

So I'm really new to Javascript, (Just started a few days ago) and one of the first projects I've tried is a simple calculator. I've got it working however the + doesn't seem to work. For example if I do 10 + 10 it gives me 1010. Users use a text box to write their numbers in and I'm not sure how to turn the value of what's the in the text box into an integer that can be added.

```
<script>    
    var num1;
    var num2;
    var operator;
    num1 = prompt("Please state your first number");
    operator = prompt("Please state your operator");
    num2 = prompt("Please state your second number");
    if (operator == "*") {
    document.write(num1 * num2);
    } else if (operator == "/") {
    document.write(num1 / num2);
    } else if (operator == "+") {
    document.write(num1 + num2);
    } else if (operator == "-") {
    document.write(num1 - num2);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The + operator is overloaded in javascript.  It is also used to concatenate strings.  If what you want is to add numbers, you have to cast your strings to ints like this:

```
<script>    
    var num1;
    var num2;
    var operator;
    num1 = prompt("Please state your first number");
    operator = prompt("Please state your operator");
    num2 = prompt("Please state your second number");
    if (operator == "*") {
    document.write(num1 * num2);
    } else if (operator == "/") {
    document.write(num1 / num2);
    } else if (operator == "+") {
    document.write(parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2));
    } else if (operator == "-") {
    document.write(num1 - num2);
    }
</script>
```